# Protractor how do you select a radio input tag?

Tags: javascript, html, protractor

This is doing my nut in...

How do you go about selecting a radio input in protractor with the value of male?

So far I've got the below code:

```
    self

        .element(by.css('.app-radio input[value=male]')).click()
        .clickButtonByText('Submit');
```

This line below is what I've got so far however I get an undefined function in my terminal every time its run:

`.element(by.css('.app-radio input[value=male]')).click()`

Would really appreciate if someone could explain why this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it turns out that the selector input[value=male] wasn't being read this meant as soon as I changed it to a type of radio instead of its set value it fixed the test.

Many thanks for all comments